# Change a href sms to a href mailto with responsive design?

Tags: javascript, css, html

Is it possible to change a href sms to a href mailto if the device does not support sms i.e. the page is not being viewed on a phone (iPhone, Android, etc)?

I've managed to make a "Shout" button that uses sms to send the url of the page, but I'd like it to change to mailto when not being viewed on a phone i.e when the page is being viewed on a tablet, laptop, etc.

This is the code I've cobbled together:

```
<section id="shout">
    <button class="button shout"><a href="sms:?&body=mysite.com" class="shoutButton">Shout</a></button>
</section>
```

I'm using external CSS files to style the page and button. It seems to work on all the phones I've tried it on, so that's cool. I've looked into using @media but that doesn't seem to be the right way, and I've tried other methods without success. I've given it a pretty good go, but my skills aren't great, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: You would create both links and only show one based on a CSS `@media` query.

Comment: Cool, thanks! I'll give that a go :)

Comment: Thanks @ScottMarcus it works like a charm :)

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to up vote and mark as the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would create both links and only show one based on a **[CSS @media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)**.

```css
/* Default Style (mobile first!) */
.phone { display:inline; }
.desktop { display:none; } 


/* Desktops */
@media screen and (min-width:1024px) {
  .phone { display:none; }
  .desktop { display:inline; }  
}
```

```html
<section id="shout">
    <button class="button shout phone">
      <a href="sms:?&body=mysite.com" class="shoutButton">Shout from Phone</a>
    </button>
    <button class="button shout desktop">
      <a href="mailto:something@something.com" class="shoutButton">Shout from Desktop</a>
    </button>
</section>
```